# Open a page in a pdf using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am working to open a specific page of a pdf using VBA in Excel.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim p As Long, i As Long

'there is a space after exe
ExeFilepath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader 2015\Reader\AcroRd32.exe "

Filepath = "\\ch3ww0001\fold1\sample.pdf"
Filename = "sample.pdf"

p = Shell(ExeFilepath & Filepath, vbNormalFocus)

another try:
'p = Shell(ExeFilepath + "/A ""page=1"" " + Filepath, vbNormalFocus)

SendKeys "%DG" & [D148] & "+{ENTER}"

For i = 1 To 10 ^ 4
    DoEvents
Next

'AppActivate p, True

SendKeys "%DG" & [D148] & "+{ENTER}"
End Sub
```

I want to link different pages in a pdf document. Those pages are listed in cells from D148 to D160.

I want to click different cells of D148-D160 to open the page in the sample.pdf.

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html worked for me in Firefox

Comment: can you give more instructions about the operation details?

Answer (score 0):

After trying for many times I found the right way to do this:

using the below shell command can fix this problem.

But, we have to notice is that:

**The pdf file must be stored in your local Disk!! A web location can not really work.**

```
p = Shell(ExeFilepath + "/A ""page=1"" " + Filepath, vbNormalFocus)
```

Here is the complete code:

```
Sub PDF_Link(ByVal target As Range)
Dim p As Long, i As Long
ExeFilepath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader 2015\Reader\AcroRd32.exe /A ""page="
Filepathname = "C:\Work\example.pdf"
p = Shell(ExeFilepath & target + 2 & """ " & Filepathname, vbMaximizedFocus)
End Sub
```

In the code above "target" is the destiny page I want to open.

Comment: this url works for me in firefox   https://www1.eere.energy.gov/hydrogenandfuelcells/tech_validation/pdfs/fcm01r0.pdf#page=5

Comment: your URL link is a pdf document?

Answer (score 0):

I find another method to do this and verified this is ok!

```
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3    '最大化显示参数
Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2    '最小化显示参数
Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1       '正常显示参数
Const SW_HIDE = 0

Public Sub openPDFPage(ByVal myPage As Long)
Dim myLink As String
'Dim myPage As Long
Dim objIE As New InternetExplorer

myLink = "C:\Work\exapmle.pdf"
'myLink = "http://www.excelvbatutor.com/vba_book/vbabook_ed2.pdf"

'myPage = InputBox("Enter the page number")

With objIE
.Navigate myLink & "#page=" & myPage
.Visible = True
.Silent = False 
End With
ShowWindow objIE.hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED

End Sub
```